# Position components inside a bootstrap panel-heading

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Using bootstrap, how can horizontally align components within a panel-heading? In order to have: title : aligned to left, btn1  : centered, btn2  : aligned to the right.

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">title</h3>

            <button class="btn">btn1</button>

            <button class="btn">btn2</button>
        </div>

        <div class="panel-body">
            text
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried to create a bootstrap class "row" and columns, but the row goes outside the panel-heading since the panel is inside another col-md-6:
[image: result of using columns]

Comment: add class pull-right to h3

Answer (score 30, accepted):

A right way to go with .row and .col is like this

```
<div class="panel panel-default container-fluid">
    <div class="panel-heading row">
        <div class="col-xs-4"><h3 class="panel-title">title</h3></div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 text-center"><button class="btn">btn1</button></div>
        <div class="col-xs-4"><button class="btn pull-right">btn2</button></div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        text
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j7u53eav/3

Comment: The components are aligned perfectly using your code. However the row goes beyond the horizontal limits of the panel as shown in my question. and it looks like the title is not vertically aligned with the other components.

Comment: In such case, you can put it inside a container or container-fluid.
http://jsfiddle.net/j7u53eav/1/

Comment: This is working perfectly for me, it should be the accepted answer as soon as it's edited to look like the linked fiidle.

Comment: This gets me most of the way there. However, since it is now a container-fluid, you cannot eliminate the padding in the "body"; for example when you drop the panel-body and insert a tables that should go from left to right borders. The "virtual" padding (column padding plus container-fluid padding) is also doubled.

Answer (score 3):

Using Ch.Idea's answer as a jumping-off point, you can add a row class to your `panel-heading`. However, you do not need to make the panel a `container-fluid`.

Since the Bootstrap `row` class adds negative margins, you just need to remove them. Assuming every time a `row` is added to a `panel-heading` you would want this behaviour, it's as simple as adding some CSS:

```
.panel-heading.row {
  margin: 0
}
```

Since columns already have padding, you can take it further by removing the left and right from the row as well:

```
.panel-heading.row {
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}
```

And for the sake of thoroughness, a modified copy of Ch.Idea's work:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading row">
        <div class="col-xs-4"><h3 class="panel-title">title</h3></div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 text-center"><button class="btn">btn1</button></div>
        <div class="col-xs-4"><button class="btn pull-right">btn2</button></div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        text
    </div>
    <table class="table">
      <!-- insert rest of table here -->
    </table>
</div>
```

And a modified jsfiddle showing full-width tables:

http://jsfiddle.net/my7axd1b/3/